# How to slice a string with different starting and end points in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, slice

I have a string like `rna = "UACGAUGUUUCGGGAAUGCCUAAAUGUUCCGGCUGCUAA"` and I want to iterate through the string and capture the different strings which start with `'AUG'` and with `'UAA'` or `'UAG'` or `'UGA'`.

This is the code I've written so far:

```
rna = "UACGAUGUUUCGGGAAUGCCUAAAUGUUCCGGCUGCUAA"      # start --> AUG; STOP --> UAA, UAG, UGA
hello = " "
n = 3
list = []
for i in range(0, len(rna), n):
    list.append(rna[i:i+n])

for i in list:
    if i == "AUG":
        hello += i
        i = i + 1
        if i != "UAA" or "UAG" or "UGA":
            hello += i
```

This is giving me a type error:-
[image: error]

Comment: Please include the error message for clarity of the error.

Comment: _What_ type error? Give a [mre]. And note you're making this mistake: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/3001761

Comment: what is `I` at the last line?

Comment: Oh sorry, it was supposed to be a small i, but autocorrect made it capital. In the code it is a small i.

Comment: Pardon me, but I don't understand why `i = i+1` is required here. The loop works without it.

Comment: Please don't include pictures of text content - they can't be searched and indexed, don't scale like text would and are completely inaccessible to users with e.g. screen readers. But fundamentally the error tells you what the problem is - `i` is a _string_ (you literally just compared it to `"AUG"` so I guess you know that) so `+ 1` has no meaning when applied to it.

Comment: It seems that use `i` sometimes as a list index (`i = i + 1`) sometimes to refer to the list content (`i == "AUG"`). This can't work and you will naturally get `TypeError` exception, as the one you got.

Comment: Also, this line does not make sense much: `if i != "UAA" or "UAG" or "UGA":'
I suppose you must write like this: `if i != "UAA" or 1!= "UAG" or i!= "UGA":`  or you may choose to write it in a list format to get all conditions into one line: `if i == "AUG" or i not in ['UAA', 'UAG', 'UGA']:`
Here is the result you get at the end:
`UACGAUGUUUCGGGAAUGCCUAAAUGUUCCGGCUGC`

Comment: Please check ```str.index()``` : https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in this line of code:

```
if i != "UAA" or "UAG" or "UGA":
            hello += i
```

You should check each value of object `i` alone:

```
if i!= "UAA" or i!= "UAG" or i!= "UGA":
            hello += i
```

Or simply you can check for the condition:

```
 if i not in ["UAA", "UAG", "UGA"]:
           hello += i
```

Also you can't concatenate string value with int value in this line of code:

```
i = i + 1
```

You should cast `1` to string data type.